# C++ Creating Child Class from a Parent Class that's already been initialised

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have a class "Player". Its members are simple strings and ints and I've got Getters and Setters for each of these...basic stuff: (there's a load of members so I've just given 3 to shrink the code):

***PLAYER.H***

```
class Player
{
private:
string Name;
string Role;
    int FFDefence;
    ......etc

public:
//constructor function
Player(
string Name = "Not Stated",
string vRole = "Not Stated",
    int vFFDefence = 0,
    ......etc
    )


//Getter Functions
string GetName() const;
string GetRole() const;
    int GetFFDefence() const;
    .....etc

//Setter Functions
void SetName (string x);
void SetRole(string x);
    void SetFFDefence(int x);
    ......etc
    };
```

***PLAYER.CPP***

```
Player::Player( string vName,
string vRole,
int vFFDefence,
......etc
{
Name = vName;
Role = vRole;
FFDefence = vFFDefence,
......etc
}
//getter functions
string Player::GetName() const {return Name; };
string Player::GetRole() const {return Role; };
int Player::GetFFDefence() const {return FFDefence; };
.....etc
//Setter Functions
void Player::SetName(string x) { Name = x ; };
void Player::SetRole(string x) { Role = x ; };
void Player::SetFFDefence(int x) { FFDefence = x ; };
......etc
```

So yeah - pretty bog standard......now I have a second class where one of the member functions is a Player Class itself.

***BATTER.H***

```
class Batter
{
private:
Player ID;
int Touch;
....etc

public:
Batter(Player vID, int vTouch = 0....etc);
//Getter Functions
string GetRole() const;
    int GetFFDefence() const;
    int GetBFDefence() const;....and so on.
```

OK - that's the code out of the way!!!!

So I've got it doing everything I want in terms of passing variables in and out....so I can create

```
Player Dave ("Dave", "Opener", 98, ....etc)
```

then later on (when I need it) create

```
Batter OnStrike (Dave, 10, .....etc)
```

All gravy....OK so I've started looking into inheritance and realized this is what I should be doing....back converting not a problem (did this with arrays and vectors the other day)...

Here's my problem:

With what I've got now, I can create "Player Dave" and then pass him into the subclass of Batter whenever I need to. How do I do the same with traditional inheritance? How do I take a specific instance (already created) of Player and use that as the parent for a specific instance of the child class Batter? As far as I can deduce at the moment, you need to create both at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Just initialize your base object with the object provided:

```
class Player
{
  Player(Player const&); // copy constructor (might be implicitly generated)
  ...
};

class Batter:
  public Player
{
  Batter(Player const& p, other arguments):
    Player(p),
    ...
  {
    ...
  }
};
```

On the other hand, there's the question whether inheritance of `Batter` from `Player` is the right tool in your case. The fact that you pass a `Player` object to construction hints at the fact that a Player may *become* a batter, and maybe later also stop being a batter. That is, `Batter` is actually a *role* which the player may temporarily have. Therefore it may be a better idea to separate the `Player` object from the role, by having a separate `Role` hierarchy where `Batter` and `Pitcher` derive from `Role`, and `Player` has a method which returns the current role, and another which can assign another role to the player.

Comment: OK - so let me get this right in my head. By adding the inheritance tag (in this case ": public Player") what I'm actually doing is giving access to the child class the members and functions of a "generic", or blank, parent class. In other words if I didn't have a member 'Player' in the Batter class, I could still try and use functions from 'Player' class even though I hadn't initialized the parent class?

Comment: ACK! Sorry, didn't realise 'copy constructor' was an actual term..(like I said, self teaching and only a few weeks in)....I'll go and read up on them...

Comment: Get a book, stop trying to learn a highly complicated language via stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

The idea with polymorphism is that if you have some class:

```
class Batter : public Player
```

Then every batter is also a player.  So, for example, if you had a batter called `dave`, you'd be able to use `dave` wherever a Player was expected.  You could for example:

```
int FunctionThatDoesSomething(Player &p, string some_parameter, ...);

...

FunctionThatDoesSomething(dave, "foo", ...);
```

Be careful to avoid slicing, which is when you accidentally make a base class copy of a subclass (this does not preserve subclass specific state.  If you need to pass `dave` around, make sure you only *refer* to `dave`, don't copy `dave`.  `dave` doesn't like to be copied.)

How exactly you build your players and batters is up to you.  For example, your might have constructors with these signatures:

```
Player::Player(string name, string role, int vFFDefense);
Batter::Batter(Player &p, int vTouch, int moreStats);
```

Under some circumstances this might be convenient, but it's not particularly efficient because you have to create and copy the base class (not that efficiency is a big deal for small classes like this, but there's no point in *trying* to do things the dumb way).  You would be better off making a constructor that takes everything it needs, and uses subobject initialization:

```
Batter::Batter(string name, string role, int vFFDefense, int moreBaseStats, int vTouch, int moreStats) : Player(name, role, vFFDefense, moreBaseStats)
{
    ...
```

But your implementation is ultimately up to you.

Comment: ....4.... This is how I understand it, but does that mean I have to use the Getter Functions from the previously created 'Player' in order to make the new Base 'Player' the same?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how you actually want your code factored.
Will a given `Player` ever become anything other than a `Batter`?  If they can, then it is probably best to use aggregation (in a similar way to how you do now).

If you are aggregating then maybe use another class to hold the data.  You could have a PlayerInfo class or struct and aggregate that:

```
struct PlayerInfo
{
    string role_;
    int ff_defence_;
    ...
};

class Player 
{
public:
    Player(PlayerInfo const& info)
        : info_(info)
    {}
    virtual ~Player() = 0;
    virtual void doSomething();

    PlayerInfo const& getPlayerInfo() const { return info_; }
private:
    PlayerInfo info_;
};

class Batter : public Player
{
public:
    Batter(PlayerInfo const& info)
        : Player(info)
    {}
    virtual void doSomething();
};
```

If you actually want the inheritance then other answers here tell you what you need to do - construct an instance of `Batter` and pass on the constructor arguments to a constructor of the class you derive from (e.g. `Batter`) to initialize it.

Think carefully about what are you trying to express in your code.

The reason you would want to have `Batter` derived from `Player` is if you need virtual functions in `Player` that are implemented in `Batter` and do something different depending upon whether or not it is a `Player` or a `Batter`.

As an aside, its best to keep base classes abstract if possible, so `Player` would never be instantiated directly and would always need to be derived.  I'd recommend reading Scott Meyers 'More Effective C++' to understand why this is.  There's a section in there devoted to that.  In fact some of the finer points of inheritance and OO design in general are nicely explained.

What you may actually want is something slightly different depending upon where you anticipate your model to change, and additionally where you you need it to have the dynamic behaviour possible through the use of virtual functions?

You could have a `Player` class that has all your player specific details. Then you could have a `PlayerBehaviour` class that implements what the player does:

```
class Player;

class PlayerBehaviour
{
public:
    virtual ~PlayerBehaviour() = 0;
    virtual void doSomething(Player* player) = 0;
};
inline PlayerBehaviour::~PlayerBehaviour() {}

class BatterBehaviour : public PlayerBehaviour
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething(Player* player) {
        if (player->isAngry()) {
            throwBatOnFloor();
        }
    }
    void throwBatOnFloor();
};

class Player {
public:
    Player(...stuff...);

    void doSomething() {
        if (behaviour_.get()) {
            behaviour_->doSomething(this);
        }
    }
private:
    auto_ptr<PlayerBehaviour> behaviour_;
    // Due to the auto_ptr, the default copy and assignment operators are
    // dangerous.  You could use a smart pointer or implement 
    // these by having a clone() function in the behaviour class.
    // Therefore copy/assign are private to prevent accidental misuse.
    Player(Player const&);
    Player& operator=(Player const&);
};
```

So, inheriting `Batter` from `Player` models the situation as a `Batter` is-a `Player`.
Having a `Behaviour` models the situation as a `Player` has-a `Behaviour` such as a `Batter`.

Comment: PlayerBehaviour is essentially the same idea as the Role hierarchy suggested by @celtschk albeit more verbose.

Comment: Structs was how I originally envisaged the 'Player' Class behaving.....however through hunting about online the general advice seemed to be: "you might as well make a class" because of the private areas being safer....hmmm....might have to go back and look at it now....

Comment: You can still make it have getter/setter functions and have private data members if you want to.  This is important if you are trying to express a particular invariant between the members or constraints on what their values are allowed to be.  If it is simply a collection of independent variables then a struct is fine..  Some prefer having getter/setters regardless.

Comment: If you are turning to inheritance, you must have a reason to need virtual functions - what is that reason?

Comment: Pretty simple: a 'Player' can be a 'Batter' and a number of Batter functions require data stored in 'Player' (Think of a 'Engine' Class having a variable for its "BHP"....then having a Class 'Car' that wants to pull the GetBHP() function from 'Engine' so it can calculate its "TopSpeed" - and of course the 'Engine' Class might have other functions that are useful to have in a 'Car'....I then want to be able to stick a prebuilt engine into a new car, rather than having to create the engine at the same time.)

Comment: So in your car case, the Car has-a Engine.  'has-a' suggests that Engine should be a member of Car - i.e. you are not modelling Car is-a engine which would lead you to possibly inherit Car from Engine.
The Car can call member functions on Engine and perhaps provide its own member functions (e.g. GetBHP()) that are implemented in terms of the Engine (i.e. Car::GetBHP() calls Engine::GetBHP()).

Comment: If the Player can be a batter or can be something else then it suggests that Batter should not inherit from Player.

Comment: As mentioned it may be batter to change this to having a Player has-a Role/Behaviour.  You can pass a pointer to the behaviour when constructing it so that it can get information about the player in its implementation.

Comment: Alternatively, simply have Batter has-a Player and the batter stores the Player as a pointer (or smart pointer) to avoid copying it.

Comment: Ok great - the has-a description is definately more accurate. Need to stop thinking there's only one correct way to skin a cat, just some are messier than others....Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing aggregation here, not inheritance. A Batter has a player. Inheritance would be a batter is a player.

Your design is good, you don't want to do inheritance for this.

While it's okay to say a Batter is always a Player from a conceptual point of view in this case, when you are dealing with a Batter, much of what player describes is irrelevant and when dealing with them as a player, they may not be batting.

Baseball is a bit foreign to me, but if you went down the inheritance route, you'd have descendants of player for each role in the team and get in a right mess when your pitcher came out to bat.

A classic illustration of the inheritance route.

Is

```
Animal -> Fliers -> Bird -> Merlin
       -> Runners -> Rodent -> Gerbil
```

Where do you put Bat and Ostrich?

You are left with saying a Bat is a bird, inventing a new class FlyingRodent, or Rodent having two parents...

All of which will lead to a confusing bug fest.

View all unconscious reaches for the inheritance hammer with extreme suspicion.

Comment: OK - I've not come across aggregation yet. I'll look into it......so as a more normal example, is this aggregation? (Using class Human and class Runner).....So a human has all these stats relating to height, weight, smoker...etc. It has functions that calculate stuff too (like BMR())....now a Runner has stats like distancerun, speed, caloriesburned, and so on. It also has functions, but needs the stats encapsulated within human in order to run these functions. So I pass a Human into the Runner to work on.......Is this aggregation then?

Comment: Yes thats aggregation. if you pass one object to another it's aggregation. If you said a runner is a human, then you are saying you can only modelling humans. If runners could be dogs or horses, then aggregation is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

Stop using the "parent" and "child" terminology, think of "base" classes and "derived" classes ... that's what everyone else calls them.  "Parent" and "child" can be used in too many other ways (e.g. an object that owns another one) so it's confusing terminology if you're talking about an inheritance relationship.

The derived class contains an entire instance of the base type inside itself.  When the derived constructor starts executing the first thing it does is construct all its bases, which it does by calling their constructors.  So the derived class can control how the base is constructed by passing it the right arguments:

```
class Base {
public:
  Base(std::string nm) : name(nm) { }

protected:
  std::string name;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  // construct my base by passing name to it
  Derived(std::string name, int ii) : Base(name), i(ii) { }

private:
  int i;
};

Derived d("Dave Derived", 1);
```

This creates both the `Base` and `Derived` objects at the same time (one inside the other) which is probably what you want.

If do have an existing `Base` object and you want the base part of the derived object to be the same as that other one then you can pass it an object to copy:

```
class Base {
public:
  Base(std::string nm) : name(nm) { }
protected:
  std::string name;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  // construct my base by passing name to it
  Derived(std::string name, int ii) : Base(name), i(ii) { }

  // construct my base by passing another Base to it:
  Derived(const Base& b, int ii) : Base(b), i(ii) { }

private:
  int i;
};

Base b("Barry Base");
Derived d(b, 2);
```

This doesn't put the existing `Base` object, `b`, inside the `Derived` one, instead it makes the base object a copy of the object `b`, by calling the `Base` copy constructor, so now there are two `Base` objects, the original `b` and the one inside `d`.  This is closer to your original code, where the `Batter` contains a `Player` member, but now it's a base class not a member.

If you do want to use inheritance, the first form is probably more appropriate, where you pass *arguments* to the derived class and it uses those arguments to create the base.

Comment: OK - So am I right in thinking that, using your last 2 lines, the new copy of 'base b' just jumps in and replaces the 'default' base that was created as soon as derived d() was called? So if the Base class has the function GetName() and the default value for Name is "not stated", and 'Base b' has a spcified Name (say "dave") - when I run Derived.GetName() (in this instance) rather than "not stated" I'll get the swapped in value from 'base b' (namely "dave")?

Comment: _"the new copy of 'base b' just jumps in and replaces the 'default' base that was created as soon as derived d() was called?"_ No. Read the code. There is no "default base", the base class gets constructed by the `Base(name)` and `Base(b)` constructor invocations, until those constructors run the base doesn't exist, so there's nothing to "replace". The base name is never "not stated". Before the base class is constructed its name doesn't even exist, and in the constructor it gets constructed with the argument `nm`, by the expression `name(nm)`, so after that it's "Derived Dave" or "Barry Base"

Comment: Got it! Sorry I'm new to this and it's exactly like my French (I'm passable at writing it, but I struggle reading it)....I've swatted up on copy constructors and now it's much, much clearer. Thanks for the help!